# select element from Json String in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` for parsing JSON objects. I am able to retrieve `Events` from my JSON string, but it contains an array of events and I need a single event named `NumberEvent`. How can I get that only?

Comment: please post your sample json string

Comment: I am using                     JObject obj = JObject.Parse(item.Categories.Types.ToString());
                    JArray arr = (JArray)obj.SelectToken("Events");   and 'arr'  has value   https://gist.github.com/3606812

Comment: entire JSON string is in https://gist.github.com/3606852 .. Actually my requirement is to retrieve NumberEvent from this ..

Comment: Anybody please help me out :(

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var events in dynObj.Categories.Types.Events)
{
    foreach (var ne in events.NumberEvent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",(string)ne["event"]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help . The below code works for me            `JObject obj = JObject.Parse(item.Categories.Types.ToString());
                   
JArray arr = (JArray)obj.SelectToken("Events");              foreach (var element in arr.Select(t => arr[0["NumberEvent"]).ToList())
{                                                  Console.WriteLine("{0}",element.ToString());
}`